# ObservableCollection<T> exists in both 'System.Windows' and 'System'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

After creating a new WPF project in VS 2017 targeting .NET 4.6 as soon as I try to use `ObservableCollection<T>` in my code I get the following error which prevents the app from building:

> ObservableCollection exists in both 'System.Windows' and 'System'

In my projects I created in VS 2015 I have referenced both of these assemblies and the application worked just fine. I tried deleting contents of app's bin and obj folder, restarting VS and performing Build > Clean Solution but that did not help.

Removing reference to System.Windows allows application to build but that adversely affects other code (for example RaiseCanExecuteChanged of my DelegateCommand requires a reference to System.Windows).

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

UPDATE Here is the full error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0433  The type 'ObservableCollection' exists in both
>   'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' and 'System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Comment: you can use fully qualified name of type and specify which namespace type to use

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` should be in `System.Collections.ObjectModel`. I just followed your steps, created a WPF app with .net 4.6 in vs2017 and created an ObservableCollection in App.xaml.cs, works/builds fine. Maybe put a sample project/solution in github and we'll look at it.

Comment: @Laith Yes, I just did the same and it worked but I noticed that out of the box the project did not have a reference to System.Windows so I added the reference and it worked fine again so something weird is going on in my original project but I can't find the problem so I'm hoping someone already ran into this before and solved it...

Comment: I now added all the references I have in the original application to the new application I just created and it still builds fine...

Comment: Okay, so how is this off-topic when it is about "a specific programming problem" namely the application will not build with Visual Studio throwing exceptions involving a .NET class?

Comment: @DeanKuga, are there any updates in Nuget? You may have a package that needs an older version of `System` or `System.Windows` and it's causing a collision.

Comment: @DeanKuga: The off topic reasons being used in the close vote are: "Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself" and "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced". Given you haven't provided code to reproduce the problem and when following the steps you've given in the question you can't reproduce it either this isn't really much of a question.

Comment: I appreciate you had a genuine problem though if you have reproduced your project from scratch without the problem then do you actually still have a problem? Without reproduction steps either in terms of concrete code or at least reliable descriptive steps to create the problem it is very hard to provide any useful support.

Comment: @Leith No, all Nuget packages are up to date...

Comment: What I might suggest you could do is take your two solutions - one working and one not - and do a diff on the solution and project files to see if there are any significant differences. I suspect those files will be too big to include in the question but you should be able to do that comparison yourself without needing us to.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that ReSharper was adding a reference to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile158\System.Windows.dll

instead of:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Windows.dll

Once I removed the reference added by ReSharper and manually added the correct reference the problem was resolved.

ReSharper was detecting that DelegateCommand implementation of ICommand used by my MVVM framework needed a reference to System.Windows but was erroneusly adding a reference to System.Windows found in the NETPortable instead of System.Windows found in .NET...